# Does vehicle tire mass effect efficiency?

Tags: classical-mechanics, mass, rotational-dynamics, mass-energy, rotational-kinematics

This question has an interesting origin: A tire salesman was recommending tires (aka tyres) for a highly fuel-efficient vehicle.  He said the vehicle was light (compared to most production cars), and therefore would benefit from lightweight tires.

I questioned his logic, as even if heavy tires weigh 30 lbs and light tires weigh 17 lbs, that's only a 13 lb difference per tire.  Given that the vehicle has 4 wheels, that is 4 x 13 = 52 lb difference (at the extreme).

Now, let's say the vehicle weighs only 2300 lbs, and is driven by a 200 lb person.  That's 2500 lbs total, plus fluids.

A difference of 50 lbs only represents a 2% difference in total weight.

With a coefficient of drag of about 0.27 and a drag area of about 6.4 sqft, will this difference in weight result in any significant change in fuel efficiency?  Let's define *significant* as one tenth of one percent.

I'm not sure if there is sufficient data to generate an answer, so if we can't answer this question *specifically*, perhaps we can answer it *generally*.

We can all agree that if we increase mass of a typical car, fuel efficiency will decline.  Put a slate billiards table on the roof of any common vehicle, and the fuel efficiency will decline in typical driving conditions (if the roof doesn't collapse first).

Is there more to tire weight than just adding mass to the vehicle?  Does the fact that that the added weight has to spin around thousands of times on each trip matter?

Comment: I don't have an answer to this, but unsprung mass is very critical to the performance of cars, and tyre mass is part of that.

Comment: Also, not some much mass directly, but mass moment of inertia affects the energy needed to accelerate and thus affects efficiency.

Comment: @tfb Although I think *Unsprung Mass* would be a great idea for a band name, I'm not sure if you saying that more tyre mass would increase or decrease performance.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: it *would* be a great band name!  It is a long time since I read about this but I am reasonably sure that minimising unsprung mass is very desirable as it improves road-holding, which depends on how aggressively you can accelerate the unsprung mass down onto the road after bumps etc.